# Why doesn't C++ allow adding new methods to classes?

Tags: c++

It seems like a rather arbitrary limitation.
Aren't regular methods just like C functions with a parameter that points to the instance?

If so I don't see why adding new methods should force me to recompile the rest of my class. Why not allow adding methods via a separate amendment header and a separate amendment implementation.

Comment: TBH adding methods to a class should be a relatively rare event (assuming your project had a *design* phase).

Comment: @Galik True, but it seems he's asking a question about the technical characteristics of C++, not its design philosophy.

Comment: That sounds like an ODR violation just waiting to happen. E.g. overload resolution would work differently between translation units that see the extra method and those that don't.

Comment: ...and `virtual` (edit: and overloaded methods) makes it harder than you think. Without `virtual`, it´s no real problem. To get the implicit parameter and circumvent the restrictions of protected/private, just modify the header of the class, ie. add your method declaration there (without the need to compile the lib / object file again)

Comment: @deviantfan Good point. You should make that into an answer.

Comment: You can add all the methods you want; its called *derivation*. That is the path chosen by the language designers. And  C++ isn't decidedly unique in that design.

Comment: If you truly want to be able to add new member functions there are various problems and chances for something like it being added to the standard seem low for me. If you on the other hand only want it to look like a method call i.e. `obj.f()` instead of `f(obj)` there's currently a proposal for 'unified function call syntax' that would allow it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "adding new methods".  I suspect maybe you're interested in doing something like this: [Practical Introduction to Code Injection with AspectJ](https://theholyjava.wordpress.com/2011/09/07/practical-introduction-into-code-injection-with-aspectj-javassist-and-java-proxy/)

Comment: Because as a maintenance programmer I don't need to have to check 15 freaking places to figure out that you snuck in some function that completely changes how a class works in some random file.  There's minimal advantage to it.  If you really, really need to do it, derive a new class.

Comment: @deviantfan That's why I asked about regular not virtual methods. Excellent answer, though. I gave it a try and it really works. You can add a separate new .cc file with an expanded class definition and it does link and work correctly with the object file of the .cc file that had the older, unexpanded view of the class! If you put it into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 5):

Consider this example

```
  // in some header

  struct X
  {
      float func(float);
  };

  // and in another source file

  void caller()
  {
       X x;
       std::cout << x.func(2);     // will call X:func(float)
  }
```

Now let's say we decide to add a new version of `func()` that accepts an `int`.

```
        // in some header

  struct X
  {
      float func(float);
      void func(int);
  };

  // and in another source file

  void caller()
  {
       X x;
       std::cout << x.func(2);
  }
```

If the `caller()` function is not recompiled, there is no way to register that the function it is calling has changed - it will keep calling `X::func(float)` in the build.

Then - possibly months (or in large systems, years) after the fact - another developer makes a completely unrelated change to one of the functions in the same source file as `caller()`.   Hence that source file gets rebuilt ... finally.    Suddenly that person finds that `caller()` won't compile - with error messages that have nothing whatsoever to do with changes of code he or she is implementing.

All this happens when the offender - the programmer who introduced the new member functions but didn't trigger a recompile and rebuild - is nowhere to be seen.

The developer left behind is left to fix the mess.  With no information about what actually caused the problem, why it was working yesterday but not today, no real clue as to how to fix it properly .... but still the one who will be held responsible.

This is just one of many problems that the "arbitrary limitation" in C++ will prevent.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things comes to my mind. On one hand you need to declare the scope of the method, I presume that's the reason why you are allowed to add new operators in the way that you are suggesting.

On the other hand, you have a problem with inheritance. The compiler need to know all the virtual methods in order to include them in the vtable.

Answer (score 0):

As [deviantfan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3134621/deviantfan) said, it's no real problem really (assuming you want to add a regular (nonvirtual) method).

```
$ for file in X.hh X.cc X-1.hh X-1.cc main.cc; do echo -e "\n//--------------//$file"; cat "$file";  done                                                                                                                           

//--------------//X.hh
//X.hh
struct X {
   int foo(int);
};

//--------------//X.cc
//X.cc (available as X.o)
#include "X.hh"
int X::foo(int a){ return a+1; }

//--------------//X-1.hh
//X-1.hh
//copy X.hh and amend it
struct X {
   int foo(int);
   int bar(int);
};

//--------------//X-1.cc
//X-1.cc
#include "X-1.hh"
int X::bar(int a){ return a+2; }

//--------------//main.cc
//main.cc
#include "X-1.hh"
//^the latest definition
#include <iostream>
int main(){
  using namespace std;
  X x;
  cout << x.foo(1) << endl;
  cout << x.bar(1) << endl;
```

And now the building part:

```
$ make {X,X-1,main}.o
$ g++ {X,X-1,main}.o   #links correctly!
$ ./a.out
2
3
```

Works even if the methods access class/struct variables.

## TL;DR:

If you use a build system that uses depend files that track `#include`s, you can `make --assume-old` a header (or `touch --date='10 minutes ago' changed_header.hh`) that only changed by means of trivial method additions (no overloads or virtuals), as all old object files that depended on the old subset of the class's instance methods won't need to be recompiled.

Also, as AliciaBytes points out, there's a proposal for a [http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4474.pdf](http://unified%20function%20call%20%20syntax)
that basically allows freestanding functions to be invoked via the dot syntax, so that's basically tantamount to reopening a class for trivial function additions.

Overloaded functions aren't really a problem as you would always `#include` a particular representation of a class (or the same class + a particular set of dot-syntax mappable free-standing functions) and you could have different versions of the same class (equivalent to having one class + different sets of dot-syntax mappable free-standing functions). (unlike virtual functions, because of vtables and vtable pointers in object instances).